# Ubuntu mount points for new installation SSD and Secondary HDD

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have a question regarding a new Ubuntu installation. I have a primary SSD drive and secondary HDD drive. I am going to put home on the secondary drive and have done this with multiple installations. However over time with the number of applications I install the primary disk fills up.

What other locations should I put on the secondary drive? /usr? /var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the most of the aplications are installed in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, you should mount them on secondary HDD drive. Because `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/share` takes the most space of the entire `/usr`, you can also mount `/usr`. However, mounting these partitions will slow down your computer(start up of aplications), since they are now moved to the slower HDD.

Comment: Always glad to help. If this question was useful, please, upvote it too. Thanks!

Comment: If I could I would, need more reputation! Thanks again.

Comment: 2 years later I have the reputation. Here you go sir. Better late than never :)